# Python random.sample giving 'Sample larger than population or is negative' when sample same length as population

Tags: python

In cases where the number of items in my population is equal to the number I want sample, I get the error.

Here is a minimal example

```
import random

subset = random.sample( set([312996, 529565, 312996, 130934]) ,  4)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b816cd5c3651> in <module>()
----> 1 subset = random.sample( set([312996, 529565, 312996, 130934]) ,  4)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/random.py in sample(self, population, k)
    318         n = len(population)
    319         if not 0 <= k <= n:
--> 320             raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    321         result = [None] * k
    322         setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list

ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

EDIT

It seems that this only occurs for those 4 numbers. I tried

```
import random

subset =  random.sample( set([2, 5, 8, 9]) ,  4)
```

And I didn't get an error. I can't figure out what the issue is for the first one. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `set([312996, 529565, 312996, 130934])` has only 3 elements

```
s = set([312996, 529565, 312996, 130934])

for element in s:
    print(element)
```

**Output**

```
312996
529565
130934
```

A set only has unique elements, so the function `set()` removes the duplicate element `312996`. In your second example `set([2, 5, 8, 9])` has 4 different elements. You can avoid the error in the following manner:

```
import random

s = {312996, 529565, 312996, 130934}
subset = random.sample(s, min(len(s), 4))

print(subset)
```

**Output**

```
[130934, 312996, 529565]
```

This ensures that you never sample more elements than there are in the set.